# Open replacement for cfbstats.com NCAA football CSV's

Tags: data-request, sports

http://www.cfbstats.com/ used to publish awesome, comprehensive statistics for college football as CSV's. It looks like all their links (including from [the blog post announcing opening their data](http://www.cfbstats.com/blog/2012/09/30/opening-up/)) now point to http://coachesbythenumbers.com/sportsource-college-football-data-packages/ which is, I presume, no longer free. Their [sample file](http://coachesbythenumbers.com/wp-content/custom-php/sportsource-data-sample.zip) shows what they used to offer, does anyone know of something similar? I'd be happy with old data so long as it has the same type of stuff as that sample.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the wayback machine is your friend
http://web.archive.org/web/20140128204311/http://www.cfbstats.com/blog/college-football-data/

EDIT:
this data is now hosted on open data se's datahub.io account:
http://datahub.io/dataset/college-football-statistics-2005-2013

Comment: you should archive them and put them on github ;)

Comment: another place to consider putting the files up on is datahub.io or opendata.socrata.com

Comment: Ha! Thanks. Uh so what's the legality of sharing something that clearly at one point _was_ behind a Open Data Commons Attribution License but now may not be?

Comment: Ah someone beat me to it: https://github.com/hottubb/NCAA-Football-Analytics/tree/master/data should've looked there first, thanks again!

Comment: awesome! good to hear

Comment: @albert - can you add these to the datahub.io org?

Comment: done and done http://datahub.io/dataset/college-football-statistics-2005-2013

Answer (score 3):

I have endpoints built for all this historical data at [slingscore.com](http://slingscore.com/) (free) :)

Comment: I'm not able to connect. Is this site still available?