# Is there detailed play by play data for US NCAA football games available online?

Tags: data-request, sports

I'm looking for the availability of current and ongoing data for US college football games, specifically play by play data.  Something with the type of play called (run/pass), number of yards needed, outcome of the play (success and # yards gained, or failure), etc.  I would like to do a hobbyist analysis of play calling success, and came across a site that had a "top plays" chart for a recent game along with details of each play.  I'm reaching out to them for details on where they got that info, but I wondered if there was a known source out there with that sort of data?  Or does everyone screen scrape their own sources?

Comment: possible duplicate....but i'm not 100% on this http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3500/open-replacement-for-cfbstats-com-ncaa-football-csvs

Comment: Yeah, I came across that earlier, as well as poked around the cffbstats page, too.  I didn't see the detailed / advanced play by play data available, plus was hoping there was some sort of ongoing dataset for current dates.    It sounds like maybe everyone just scrapes the data and makes it available in their own way it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Open Data SE actually has this data for you from 2005-2013 on datahub.io. They're actually scraped from cbfstats.com:
http://datahub.io/dataset/college-football-statistics-2005-2013

Comment: Thanks!  I was hoping there was something with ongoing current data, but I had run across that data set.

Comment: then you should update your question to reflect that please